# Извлечь css из плагина FlyPlastique

Tags: c++, css, qt5

Здраствуйте. У меня такой вопрос. Как из плагина извлечь css? В qt можно методом setStyle загрузить стиль и есть плагин в линуксе  FlyPlastique. Этот плагин загружается в программу написанную на qt и теперь надо извлечь оттуда css и записать в отдельный файл. Как это сделать?

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

a.setStyle("FlyPlastique");

QStyle* style = a.style();
QFile file("style.css");

file.open(QFile::WriteOnly);

//file.write(&style);
```

Я думала сделать это таким образом, но это не правильно. Как сделать так что бы у меня появился css файл?